# Return all property names that share the same value in JS Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects and I want to return array containing only the names of the happy people and return all names when everybody is happy.
The thing I fail to get is to get all names when everybody is happy. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** This is the object.

```
  [
  { name: 'Don', disposition: 'Happy' },
  { name: 'Trev', disposition: 'Happy' },
]

function findHappyPeople(people) {

var happyPeople = Object.keys(people).filter(function(key) {
   if(people[key] === 'Happy') {
     return people[name]
   }
});

return happyPeople;
```

}

Comment: May be `return people["name"]` ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Note that `filter()` expects a boolean returned

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ It's not working.

Comment: Please add an example of `people` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of objects, so `Object.keys()` wouldn't be needed here.

You can use a `.map()` operation after the filter to end up with an array of names.

Your `people[name]` code isn't going to work because you have no `name` variable, except the global one if you're in a browser, which isn't what you want. Your data has a `.name` property, so use that.

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'Don', disposition: 'Happy' },
  { name: 'Trev', disposition: 'Happy' },
]

console.log(findHappyPeople(data));

function findHappyPeople(people) {
    return people
       .filter(function(p) { return p.disposition === "Happy" })
       .map(function(p) { return p.name });
}
```

Or with arrow function syntax:

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'Don', disposition: 'Happy' },
  { name: 'Trev', disposition: 'Happy' },
]

console.log(findHappyPeople(data));

function findHappyPeople(people) {
    return people
       .filter(p => p.disposition === "Happy")
       .map(p => p.name);
}
```

Comment: Maybe dumb question but I get "p is not defined" error?

Comment: @squeekyDave: I made a live demo in the answer. It works. Make sure the function parameter is define properly.

Comment: It works perfectly now, thank you for bringing clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

i think it is a bit cleaner with reduce honestly instead of a filter and a map and also a bit lighter

```
data.reduce((names, person) => {
    if(person.disposition === 'Happy') names.push(person.name);

    return names;
}, [])
```